# access control using zkemkeeper.dll but not unlocking using #application.for zkteco c3-100 device

Tags: c#, sdk, access-control, zkteco

I'm using `ACUnlock()` function but its not working

```
if (axCZKEM.ACUnlock(iMachineNumber, iDelay)) {
    axCZKEM.RefreshData(iMachineNumber);
    ...
}
```

It's not giving any error or exception but it's not unlocking.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Mine issue was resolved. The problem was in the SDK. I just used a different version of ZKtecho SDK and issue resolved !